# Retrieving nodes outside bounding box for ways that overflow it (osmosis command line tools)

Tags: osmosis

I am able to successefully filter all ways (roads in particular) that are within a given bounding box. I am using the tag "--used_nodes" to fetch only the nodes composing those ways.

My problem is that the ways are "truncated" if they overflow the bouding box. Indeed, the way and its list of nodes is correctly retrieved even if it overflows the box, but the corresponding used nodes that are fetched are only those that are within the box. The others are missing in the produced file after filtering data. I would like to get them, even if they are outside the box. Below an illustration of my question.

[image]

Is there a proper way to achieve this ?

Comment: So you want the predicate "cross" or "intersect", not "within"?

Comment: Yes exactly, but I cannot find a way to do that with the osmosis command line tool. By default, --bounding-box flag gets rid of outer nodes..

Comment: I am so dumb... I missed the "completeWays=yes" option for --bounding-box in the official documentation.. Thank you for having put me on the right track ! Now it works !

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, one needs to set `"completeWays=yes"`
The documentation mentioned is e.g. [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.41)

A full example of a command would be e.g.:

```
osmosis  --read-pbf us-west-latest.osm.pbf  \
 --tf accept-ways highway=* --used-node  \
 --bounding-box \
 left=-123.838 top=49.14953 \
 right=-114.131 bottom=44.55486 \
 completeWays=yes \
 --write-pbf box_highways.osm.pbf
```